# Geth syncing - Jan 18, how much time should wait before I call it quits. (First time miner)

Tags: synchronization, state-trie, geth-debugging

After 3 days; current status:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4829460,
  highestBlock: 4829665,
  knownStates: 19675738,
  pulledStates: 19646971,
  startingBlock: 4828906
}
```

Getting ti

Comment: Have you found out how long it takes? Is there a way to calculate the progress?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all clear what the words "Jan 18" mean in the question, but if you're that close after only three days, I would say you're doing okay. I've seen some notes (sorry - no reference) saying rebooting your machine sometimes helps. You might want to try that if it looks stuck.

You should include the node (parity, geth?) that you're running and the command line options you used to start the node to make it easier for people to help you.